# ¿Es posible cuadro de texto con dos colores de letras?

Tags: python, tkinter

## Función para agregar nueva consulta

```
def agregar_consulta(self):
    b = datetime.today()
    self.fecha_actual = datetime.strftime(b, "%d/%m/%Y") 
    self.mitipo_consulta1='Consulta'
    self.mitexto_consulta1=self.fecha_actual + "\n" + 'Resultado Actual:' + self.resultado1 + "\n" + 'Resultado Nuevo:' + self.resultado2
    self.miimagen1_consulta=StringVar()
```

## Aqui ubico el cuadro de texto

```
    self.mitexto_consulta=Text(frame63, width=90, height=16, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'))
    self.mitexto_consulta.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    scrollvert1=ttk.Scrollbar(frame63, orient="vertical", command=self.mitexto_consulta.yview)
    scrollvert1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ens")
    self.mitexto_consulta.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollvert1.set)
```

#Yo utilizo esta variable self.mitexto_consulta1 para insertar información den el cuedro de texto, y realizo un salto de lineas con \n, pregunto le puedo cambiar el color de texto despues de  cada salto de linea en em mismo cuadro de texto?, en realidad no se si eso se puede hacer, me gustaria cambiar el color de la letra una vez realizado el salto de linea.

Comment: Que es lo que deseas que suceda? la primera linea amarillo, la segunda rojo, la tercera verde, etc o en un ciclo (primera rojo, segunda verde, tercera rojo, cuarta verde...)?

Comment: Si es en forma de ciclo, que patron buscas? ej: rojo rojo verde amarillo

Comment: Si ese no es el caso, que quieres que suceda cuando se acaben los colores a usar?

Comment: Yo tengo un cuadro de texto, donde inserto una cadena, mi pregunta es si puedo inserta una linea de color diferente para resaltar parte del texto en el cuadro de diaologo o cuadro de texto y el usuario pueda ver eso resaltado, no se como hacerlo

Comment: Estoy insertando una cadena en un cuadro de texto, quiero resaltar, o cambiar el color, he probado con varias opciones pero me dan error, ¿Se puede cambar el color de una en un mismo cuadro de texto, ej, las 2 primera filas con color azul y el resto negro, si esposible harcelo, me gustarian que me ayudaran, si no es posible tambien agradezco me lo digan para desgastarme intentandolo, muchas gracias deantemano.

Answer (score 2):

en Python puedes cambiar el color del texto (de la consola) de varias formas una de ellas es podria ser:

```
print(chr(27)+"[1;33m"+"Texto en negrita de color amarillo") 
print("\x1b[1;33m"+"Texto en negrita de color amarillo") 
print("\033[4;35m"+"Texto en negrita y subrayado de color morado") 
print("\033[4;35m"+"Texto en negrita y subrayado de color morado")
```

Si es esto lo que buscas, puedes encontrar mas detalles [aquí](https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/09/dar-color-las-salidas-en-la-consola.html)

Comment: El OP está usando la caja de texto de Tkinter. Probé tu código en una caja de texto y no funciona, pero gracias igual por tu contribución c:

Answer (score 2):

La verdad es que no puedo ver como cargas los datos en el texto, así que hago un ejemplo funcional para que lo apliques a tu código:

```
#-*- coding: utf  -8 -*-
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random


texto="""Prueba de
entrada para
texto multilinea
en color"""

ver=texto.split("\n")
```

Esto es simple, importo las bibliotecas, creo un texto y genero una lista a partir de ese texto

```
root = Tk()
text = Text(root,width=90, height=16, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'))
text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
scrollvert1=ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=text.yview)
scrollvert1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ens")
text.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollvert1.set)
```

La ventana, el contenedor con lo que pusiste, sin usar una clase, no tengo ganas de tipear de más.

```
colores=['yellow','blue','brown','orange','grey','red']
text.insert(INSERT, texto)
```

Una lista con los colores posibles e inserto el texto en el campo.

```
for x in range(1,len(ver)+1):
    color= random.choice(colores)
    text.tag_add(x,float(x),f"{x}.{len(ver[x-1])}")
    text.tag_config(str(x), background=color)
   
root.mainloop()
```

Bueno, un bucle con el largo de la lista que contiene el texto
Un colo al azar de la lista de colores.
Para modificar el color hay que crear un tag(no sé la traducción) con un nombre, que en este caso es el entero del bucle, una posición inical que es un flotante y es cada "línea" del campo y una posición final que es el inicio de la linea más el largo que ocupa.
Por último configuramos el tag creado con un color.
Hay mucha info en la ayuda de tkinter sobre lo que intenté explicar.
Por supuesto que los colores se pueden repetir porque no hice un método para evitarlo.

Comment: Gracias, si esto es lo que buscaba, voy a probarlo, muchas gracias por la explicación